# UpdateView - object has no attribute 'object

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to verify that the user updating the post is the author of post.

My code looks like this(releavant parts):

```
class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['body']
    template_name = 'forum/post_update_form.html'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user != self.object.author:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super(CreatePostView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
'UpdatePostView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

At this point, I'm a little confused, since the documentation says: `When using UpdateView you have access to self.object, which is the object being updated.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overriding too early. `dispatch` is the first method called, before `self.object` has been set. You'd need to either override `get` and `post` and do the check in each one (after calling `super`), or call `get_object` explicitly in your dispatch method.